# Remove page number, title and url - window.print() on internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I want to print a page in my Angular app. On the Internet Explorer the page numbers, url and title are always visible.

I already tried it with

```
@page { 
 size: auto !important;  
 margin: 0mm !important; 
}
```

in the css file. But it seems to have no effect in the IE.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: There is probably no way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can only be done via your browser settings:

Click on settings icon on right of your browser.  Hover over print then in sub menu choose page setup

You can change the header and footer in there

The page number and title are in the header and the url and date are in the footer - just set the drop downs to `-Empty-`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this javascript code.N.B you need to make custom print button.

```
document.getElementById("printButton").addEventListener('click',printPage);
function printPage(){
  var curURL = window.location.href;
  history.replaceState(history.state, '', '/');
  window.print();
  history.replaceState(history.state, '', curURL);
}
```